# LLVM IR instruction insertion

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

In a Function iterator loop when i put the following code

```
 for(BasicBlock::iterator BI = BB->begin(), BE = BB->end(); BI != BE; ++BI)          
        {
             if(isa<StoreInst>(&(*BI)) )
                {
                   if(i==0)
                   {
                    Value *Two = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context), 2);
                     Value *Three = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context), 3);
                      Instruction *Add = BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction::Add, Two, Three,"addresult",(Instruction*)BI);
                        i=1;
                    }
                    }
                    }
```

then i am getting error(while applying this pass on the following  input.bc file
it is input.ll of that input.bc file

```
 define void @_Z3minv() #0 {
entry:
%k = alloca i32, align 4
  %i = alloca i32, align 4
 %j = alloca i32, align 4
 store i32 10, i32* %i, align 4
 store i32 5, i32* %j, align 4
 %0 = load i32* %i, align 4
 %1 = load i32* %j, align 4
 %add = add nsw i32 %0, %1
 store i32 %add, i32* %k, align 4
 ret void}
```

with the command opt -load ../Release+Asserts/lib/Testing.so -insert
(insert is my pass name)
I am getting:-
while deleting i32
use still stuck around after Def is destroyed : %addresult =add i32 2, 3

can anyone please explain what is happening here .

Comment: You're not deleting anything here; Please provide a minimal complete IR code sample, as long with an input file that causes the problem

Comment: @Eli Bendersky I have edited my question ,so please tell me what i am missing . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I get these when something is not fully attached to a module. Either the created instructions are not in a block or a block is not in a function or a function is not in a module. Basically it was not reachable when deleting.

Comment: Actually i want to insert one instruction into my LLVM IR .ll file,so i am searching for a way to insert. Binary operator is using Value Two and Three but after finishing insertion Value Two and Three are deleted but their use still left in Binaryoperation. Is there any way to insert those values also apart from Load and Store.(Correct me if i misunderstood something)